# AJAX data returned is not correct

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have this posts.php where it uses a unique id to view different contents. For example: `posts.php?id=1` will display all data on my table which has an id of 1, id = 2 for 2 and so on...

This id is held on a php var `$post_id` on each page and in order to send this php variable on my jquery/javascript, I used:

```
<div id = "dummy_disp" style = "display: none;">
  <?php echo htmlspecialchars($post_id); ?>
</div>

<div id = "real_commentsno"></div>
```

( I know, not the best way to do it but it works)

It connects to my js:

```
var commentid = document.getElementById("dummy_disp");
      var commentidreal = commentid.textContent;

      $.ajax ({
        type:"GET",
        url:"php/post_comments.php",
        data:'comid='+commentidreal,
        success: function(data){
          $("#real_commentsno").html(data);
        }
      });
```

I have this `post_comments.php` where it has:

```
$cc_g_postid = htmlentities($_GET['comid']);
$cc_postid = mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$cc_g_postid);


 $cc_sql  = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE postuniqueid = '$cc_postid' ";
 $cc_result = mysqli_query($con,$cc_sql);

 $cc_count = mysqli_num_rows($cc_result);

  echo $cc_count;
```

When I try to view the `post_comments.php` alongside with the attached url var: `?comid=1` the page displays `2` which is correct since post `id=1` on my table has only 2 comments. But when I go to my `posts.php` the ajax displays 0, not 2. I tried looking at the console, there were no errors.

Is there anything I missed or misdo? Also, `post_comments.php` is on located on  `mypage/php/post_comments.php` whereas `posts.php` is located on `mypage/posts.php` ( i dunno if this is necessary info but maybe the url is jamming it or something? )

Comment: [Have you watched the AJAX request / response in the browser's developer tools? Have you included the jQuery library in the project? Are there any errors reported? Are you running this on a web-server?](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: `data: { comid: commentidreal }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the DIV has newlines and spaces around the ID number. You need to remove all this whitespace.

```
  var commentidreal = commentid.textContent.trim();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This solves it. I just don't understand why there were whitespace? If I echo the php var, it doesn't display any whitespace at all?

Comment: Echo the variable inside a `<pre>...</pre>` block so you can see all the formatting. Otherwise all the whitespace gets merged.

Comment: There's whitespace because you have a newline after `<div id = "dummy_disp" style = "display: none;">`, you indent the line with `<?php echo`, and then you have another newline before `</div>`.